# DateTimeFormatter Support for Single Digit Day of Month and Month of Year

Tags: java, date, java-8, java-time

`DateTimeFormmater` doesn't seem to handle single digit day of the month:

```
String format = "MM/dd/yyyy";
String date   = "5/3/1969";
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat(format).parse(date));
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format)));
```

In this example, `SimpleDateFormat` correctly parses the date, but `DateTimeFormatter` throws an exception.  If I were to use zero padded dates, e.g., "05/03/1969", both work.  However, if either the day of month or the month of year are single digit, then `DateTimeFormatter` throws an exception.

What is the right `DateTimeFormatter` format to parse both one and two digit day of month and month of year?

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I'm also looking into a java8 solution to parse 1 or 2 digits month, or 2 or 4 digits year.

Answer (score 111):

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

> **Number**: If the count of letters is one, then the value is output using the minimum number of digits and without padding.

So the format specifier you want is `M/d/yyyy`, using single letter forms. Of course, it will still parse date `String`s like `"12/30/1969"` correctly as for these day/month values, two digits are the “minimum number of digits”.

The important difference is that `MM` and `dd` require zero padding, not that `M` and `d` can’t handle values greater than 9 (that would be a bit… unusual).

Comment: I faced the same issue in Dart, but with above solution implemented using intl package, it is working properly now. Thank you.

Comment: This one worked, well explained @Holger. Link for documentation was helpful too.

Answer (score 16):

In Java 8 Date Time API, I recently used

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/dd/yyyy"))
            .toFormatter();

System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("10/22/2020", formatter));
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("2/21/2020", formatter));
```

Comment: Why include the second pattern? What value would you expect to be parsed by the second but not the first?

Comment: @JonSkeet very good suggestion by you. I have just removed the second pattern as single pattern is able to parse both type of values like 10/22/2020 and 2/22/2020

Comment: this is an great solution. I could add multiple patterns. thanks

Answer (score 3):

The best approach to deal with this kind of problem , That is number of different digits in Date (in day , month or year ) is to use this pattern : **(M/d/[uuuu][uu])** .

Example:

```
String date = "7/7/2021"; // or "07/07/2021" or "07/7/21" etc
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(
date,DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/[uuuu][uu]"));
```

Here uuuu/uu handle four and two digits year.

Answer (score 0):

```
private final static DateTimeFormatter BIRTH_DAY_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-M-d");

public static LocalDate convertDate(String dateString) {
    return LocalDate.parse(dateString, BIRTH_DAY_FORMATTER);
}
```

You can use this way in your Utils class and since DateTimeFormatter is threadsafe, you can use it as a field in your Utils class