# How to do subtraction from a particular date using Java

Tags: java

I am encountering an issue which is related to Java Date Function.

I'm getting the date from Application (example: 6/5/18) which is in MM/DD/YY format. Now I need to do -2 from the date. I know how to do -2 from current system date using calendar object (see the below code).

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();      
cal.add(Calendar.DATE,-2);
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
String PastDate = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
info("Date is displayed as : "+ PastDate );
```

I'm not able to put the date which I'm getting from Application in this format. Can someone please help me? (Any other way to do it would also be fine)

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? 1.8?

Comment: I guess you have to build a Calendar object from the date you're getting from the application

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome.  `Calendar` is outdated too. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use Java 8 compatible Date and Time types.

If you use [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) then this is the solution:

```
LocalDate.now().minusDays(2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am doing it in OATS tool where I can't import this package - java.time.LocalDate. Also, I will have a particular date to do subtraction. LocalDate.now().minusDays(2) will give the 2 days older date from current date. This is not really the solution to my problem. If you can guide me more on this, it would really be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it seems that you have the challenge in dealing with formatting, and then doing the subtraction.

I would recommend Java Date and Time Apis for this purpose, using a formatter.

A junit method to achieve your requirement is given below

```
@Test
public void testDateFormatUsingJava8() {
    CharSequence inputdateTxt = "6/5/18";
    DateTimeFormatter  formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yy");
    LocalDate inputDate = LocalDate.parse(inputdateTxt, formatter);
    System.out.println(inputDate.minusDays(2L).format(formatter));
}

@Test
public void testDateCalenderUsingStringSplit() {
    String inputdateTxt = "6/5/18";
    String[] dateComponenets = inputdateTxt.split("//");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    //Know where are the year month and date are stored.
    cal.set(Integer.parseInt(dateComponenets[2]), Integer.parseInt(dateComponenets[0]), Integer.parseInt(dateComponenets[2]) );
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE,-2);
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yy");
    String pastDate = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
    System.out.println("Date is displayed as : "+ pastDate );
}

@Test
public void testDateCalenderUsingJavaUtilDateApi() throws ParseException {
    String inputdateTxt = "6/5/18";
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yy");
    Date date = dateFormat.parse(inputdateTxt);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE,-2);
    String pastDate = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
    System.out.println("Date is displayed as : "+ pastDate );
```

**The reason why I use "M/d/yy" is because your question does not pad the date and month fields in the input date with a zero.** If there is a guarantee that you receive a padded value in the date and month field, using "MM/dd/yy" is suggested.

See the following answer for your reference :

[DateTimeFormatterSupport for Single Digit Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27571377/datetimeformatter-support-for-single-digit-day-of-month-and-month-of-year)

EDIT: considering the limitation to not use Java 8 Date Time APIs, I have added two other alternatives to solve the problem. The OP is free to choose any one of the solutions. Kept the Java 8 solution intact for information purposes.

Comment: This is until now the best and most precise answer to the question. One might consider the method name `random` a bit — random?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah, I also agree with the fact that this is the most precise answer to my query. I haven't used Java Date and Time because the version of OATS, I will not be able to use this. Your answer looks perfect to me, but I'm not able to use it.

Comment: @OleV.V. thanks. Agreed. The method name was a bit too random. Have modified it to suit the context. It was a result of a quick tryout in one test class of the feature branch code.. :)

Comment: @Chandrima, I have added alternative solutions too. choose the one you like!

Comment: @Amal - Thanks a lot for the solution. I have taken the third option and it worked.

Comment: @Chandrima Great to know that. Can you mark this solution as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(2018, 5, 6); // add this, setting data from the value you parsed
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE,-2);
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
    String PastDate = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
    System.out.println("Date is displayed as : "+ PastDate);
```