# Verifying if date from String is the last day of the month

Tags: java, groovy

My input string date is as below:

```
String date = "1/31/2022";
```

I am transforming to a date:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

How do I know if my date is the last day of the month?

E.g.: for a String "1/31/2022" the output should be true. For 2/2/2023 it should be fast.

This is to run in Groovy in Jenkins but I believe I could use java as well

Comment: Do yourself a great favour. Immediately stop using `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. In this case use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter` both from java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat` is obsolete. I'd use the modern stuff from the `java.time` package.

Use single character `M` and `d` if not padding single-digit values with a leading zero.

```
DateTimeFormatter MY_FORMAT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/uuuu");

LocalDate x = LocalDate.parse("1/31/2022", MY_FORMAT);
if (x.getDayOfMonth() == x.lengthOfMonth()) {
  // it is the last day of the month
}
```

Comment: There is a mismatch between input and format, `MM` should be changed or input should have leading zeros.

Comment: The question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27571377/datetimeformatter-support-for-single-digit-day-of-month-and-month-of-year addresses the item that @Eritrean mentioned.  I think as written in the answer, that code probably throws an exception.

Comment: Thank you.  I just had to replace MM/dd/uuuu to M/d/uuuu for it to work. Thank you

Comment: I corrected the format problem in this Answer, as mentioned in these Comments: `M/d/uuuu` rather than `MM/dd/uuuu`.

Comment: Good Answer. Another route is using [`YearMonth::atEndOfMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html#atEndOfMonth()).